# Некорректная работа Timer во Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, время, actionscript

Писал программу на ActionScript 3, потом скинул другу, и оказалось, что в готовой swf-ке таймер неправильно работает. Специально замерял, за минуту по таймеру прошло 36 секунд! 
При этом, когда компилирую из Flash Professional все нормально.
Как бы это исправить? Или может чем заменить?
Может то, что я обновляю текстовое поле каждую сотую часть секунды как-то влияет на работоспособность таймера?

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10, 6000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateText);
timer.start();
```

Пробовал для версий Flash Player'а 11.1, 11.4, 11.8, FPS - 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Корректная работа ас3 таймера не гарантирована на интервалах меньших 30мс.

- нужно помнить об ограничениях покадровой модели работы кода в кадрах (если у вас есть такой код).
- модель выполнения код в ас3 однопоточная (кроме класса Worker) поэтому пока не завершится код в других местах приложения, метод слушатель таймера так же не будет выполнен.

Возможно что ваш таймер работает сам на себя все время.

http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

> ...если SWF-файл настроен на
> проигрывание с частотой 10 кадров в
> секунду, т.е. с интервалом в 100
> миллисекунд, а таймер настроен на
> запуск события через 80 миллисекунд,
> то событие будет запускаться примерно
> через 100-миллисекундный интервал.
> Сценарии, требующие большого объема
> памяти, также могут приводить к сдвигу
> времени отправки событий.